# Full backup vs Simple TempDB usage

Tags: backup, sql-server-2016

What is the difference in terms of I/O disk usage between Simple Backup and Full Backup?

Does full backup incur more reads and writes?

How does full backup mode impact reads and writes to TempDB's transaction log?

Comment: Are you trying to understand the recovery model or the different types of backups possible?  tempdb is a unique case in sqlserver in that it supports all other databases on the instance and is considered ephemeral with regards to the recovery model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recommends setting it to SIMPLE to limit space utilisation. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175527(v=sql.90)). From an IO perspective, SIMPLE mode will generally require the same IO because it has to retain enough transaction data to facilitate rollback of an active transaction. There is some good information on TLOG utilisation [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/10-important-sql-server-transaction-log-myths/).